# Align pgfplotstabletypeset and plot left and right

Tags: pgfplots, horizontal-alignment, pgfplotstable

I can't get the plot and the pgfplotstabletypeset to align so that they are right next to each other. Is this possible at all? Please help me.

This is what it looks like at the moment:

[image]

This is my code:

```
\begin{filecontents}{performance.data}
Konsumenten   Sekunden
1  31.944
2  16.064
3  16.099
4  16.541
5  6.611
6  6.248
7  6.345
8  6.375
9  6.26
10  3.748
\end{filecontents}
\begin{flushright}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
    \addplot[color=black, mark=x] table[x=Konsumenten, y=Sekunden] {performance.data};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{flushright}

\begin{flushleft}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
col sep=&,row sep=\\,
string type,
every even row/.style={
before row={\rowcolor[gray]{0.9}}},
every head row/.style={
before row=\toprule,after row=\midrule},
every last row/.style={
after row=\bottomrule}
]{
Konsumenten & Sekunden\\
1 & 31.944 \\
2 & 16.064 \\
3 & 16.099 \\
4 & 16.541 \\
5 & 6.611 \\
6 & 6.248 \\
7 & 6.345 \\
8 & 6.375 \\
9 & 6.26 \\
10 & 3.748 \\
}
\end{flushleft}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard `minipage` idea works here

[image]

For the future, please be sure to post a complete MWE- here's an example of one:

```
% arara: pdflatex
% !arara: indent: {overwrite: on, trace: yes}
\begin{filecontents}{performance.data}
Konsumenten   Sekunden
1  31.944
2  16.064
3  16.099
4  16.541
5  6.611
6  6.248
7  6.345
8  6.375
9  6.26
10  3.748
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{colortbl}

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[width=\textwidth]
            \addplot[color=black, mark=x] table[x=Konsumenten, y=Sekunden] {performance.data};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
    \pgfplotstabletypeset[
        col sep=&,row sep=\\,
        string type,
        every even row/.style={
            before row={\rowcolor[gray]{0.9}}},
        every head row/.style={
            before row=\toprule,after row=\midrule},
        every last row/.style={
            after row=\bottomrule}
    ]{
        Konsumenten & Sekunden\\
        1 & 31.944 \\
        2 & 16.064 \\
        3 & 16.099 \\
        4 & 16.541 \\
        5 & 6.611 \\
        6 & 6.248 \\
        7 & 6.345 \\
        8 & 6.375 \\
        9 & 6.26 \\
        10 & 3.748 \\
    }
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

If you would like captions for each object, then you can put the the above `minipage` code into a `figure` environment, and use the [`caption`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/caption/caption-eng.pdf) package's `captionof` command, as demonstrated below.

[image]

```
% arara: pdflatex
% !arara: indent: {overwrite: on, trace: yes}
\begin{filecontents}{performance.data}
Konsumenten   Sekunden
1  31.944
2  16.064
3  16.099
4  16.541
5  6.611
6  6.248
7  6.345
8  6.375
9  6.26
10  3.748
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!htb]
    \begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[width=\textwidth]
                \addplot[color=black, mark=x] table[x=Konsumenten, y=Sekunden] {performance.data};
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{Figure caption here}
    \end{minipage}%
    \begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \captionof{table}{Table caption here}
        \pgfplotstabletypeset[
            col sep=&,row sep=\\,
            string type,
            every even row/.style={
                before row={\rowcolor[gray]{0.9}}},
            every head row/.style={
                before row=\toprule,after row=\midrule},
            every last row/.style={
                after row=\bottomrule}
        ]{
            Konsumenten & Sekunden\\
            1 & 31.944 \\
            2 & 16.064 \\
            3 & 16.099 \\
            4 & 16.541 \\
            5 & 6.611 \\
            6 & 6.248 \\
            7 & 6.345 \\
            8 & 6.375 \\
            9 & 6.26 \\
            10 & 3.748 \\
        }
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively you can set the baseline of the TikZ picture or you can use `subcaption` package to get individual caption labels etc.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable,booktabs,colortbl}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\pgfplotstableread{
Konsumenten   Sekunden
1  31.944
2  16.064
3  16.099
4  16.541
5  6.611
6  6.248
7  6.345
8  6.375
9  6.26
10  3.748
}\mytable

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.center)]
\begin{axis}[width=0.5\textwidth]
    \addplot[color=black, mark=x] table[x=Konsumenten, y=Sekunden] {\mytable};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
%
\hfill
%
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
every even row/.style={
before row={\rowcolor[gray]{0.9}}},
every head row/.style={
before row=\toprule,after row=\midrule},
every last row/.style={
after row=\bottomrule}
]\mytable
\end{document}
```